# Is it possible for the Fn key to be always preselected on a Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I hate pressing the Fn key each time I need one of the F1, F8, F9 keys.

Is there a way to have it pre-selected when I am programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *System Preferences » Keyboard*, select the option "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

[image]

Comment: cool, so when I want the other keys, I use the fn key then right? perfecto!

Comment: Exactly, it turns the functionality around.